# $.post not working in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, .post

I have this code. It works with Google chrome and Firefox but I don't understand why it fails with IE 9. When I try this URL: `Login?login_username=toto&login_password=toto` it works. So I think the problem comes from `$.post` because when I try to connect in my application the form is empty so `$.post` don't send well the form.

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");


    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            'Se connecter': function() {
                $(".ajax").trigger('submit');
            },
            Retour: function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });

    $(".ajax").submit(
        function(e) {
            var login_username = $("#login_username").val(),
            login_password = $("#login_password").val();

            alert(login_username + " pass  " + login_password);

            $.post('Login',{login_username:login_username,login_password:login_password});
            document.location.reload()
            return false; // Pour empêcher le submit vers la page 'action'
        });


    $('#connect').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

});
```

Comment: you are probably calling document.location.reload() before the $.post is complete.

Comment: can you tell me what to do add to my jquerycode please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var values = {numberId: "1", companyId : "531"};

$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: "post",
  data: values,
  success: function(){
      alert("success");
      document.location.reload();
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("failure");
      $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
  }   
});
```